# git create a patch that can be applied to 2 places

Tags: git

Here is my tree:

```
----production-----------------development
```

So production is not a diverged branch but rather jsut an older commit (or a tag). Now I discovered a bugfix and I'd like it be applied to both production and development. This matters because I have a production server running code from the production snapshot and development server running latest code.

If I simply do the changes and commit, it will only affect development. My production server will not get the bugfix.

How should I do that?

Comment: Btw, this is a good example why diverged branches makes sense. The solutions Emil proposed should work, but maybe you should reconsider your workflow.

Comment: @Zeeker If I had used a diverged branch for production, what might I do now which is neater?

Comment: Take a look at knittl's comment under his answer, creating a hotfix branch and merging it into master and dev would be a clean way to solve the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply apply the patch in your production branch, and then merge it into development:

```
git checkout production
# fix your bugs
git commit -m 'fixed bug'
git checkout development
git merge production
```

Your resulting DAG will look like this:

```
---o--------------------o---------development (with merged fix)
    \                            /
     `--production (with fix) --'
```

(Left `o` is the old production branch tip, right `o` is the old development branch tip)

Comment: Note you can also create a new branch (e.g. "fix1") and commit to this branch, then merge it into both prod and dev branches (prod will fast-forward, dev will do a real merge).

Answer (score 0):

You could `git rebase -i` and insert the new commit before `production` and `development`.

> new --> production --> development

However this would require a force push and rewriting history so I would recommend you checkout from the `production` branch  make the commits then merge the commits into `production` and `development` separately.